# Python loop that returns different variables

Tags: python, variables, loops

I want to have cosine functions with frequencies from 1 to 100 so instead of writing 100 lines in the form of

```
x=linspace(-500,500,1001)
f1=cos(2*pi*1*x)
f2=cos(2*pi*2*x)
#and so on till 100
```

I want to have a loop that outputs them all, I tried this one:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
freq=[]
x=linspace(-500,500,1001)
for i in range(101):
    freq.append=cos(2*pi*i*x)
freq
```

however it does not work, I tried different combinations but I always get the message:

```
  freq[i].append=cos(2*pi*i*x)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am sure it is something simple but I could not find the problem as I am python newbie. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, the append doesn't work like that for lists. You actually have written it two different ways. In the second example you are giving it an index [i] where it is just an empty list, hence the error.

Try this instead:

```
freq.append(cos(2*pi*i*x))
```

The second problem is that because you are using i (which is an integer) and x (which is made of whole numbers) you are only ever going to get 1s in your arrays as they never calculate cos for phases other than multiples of 2*pi.

You need to divide x by some other value (perhaps the buffer length, or the sampling frequency, depending on your application) to make sure you are going to generate the signals you want.

EDIT: Here is an example that prints out the signal at each step using the number of samples in the buffer (1001) as the divisor, ensuring a whole number of cycles per buffer:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
freq=[]
x=linspace(-500,500,1001)
for i in range(101):
    freq.append(cos(2*pi*i*(x/1001.)))
    plot(freq[-1])
    show()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct syntax of the line where you get the exception:

```
     freq.append(cos(2*pi*i*x))
```